# F# Interface Implementation

Tags: interface, f#

Let say I have this interface in C# and want to implement it in F#

```
public interface IBatch
{
    System.Data.IDbConnection Connection { get; set; }
}
```

I wish to implement the interface in F# but cant figure out the correct syntax. I have something like this:

```
type public Batch = 
    interface IBatch with
        member f.Connection 
            with get() = new Devart.Data.Oracle.OracleConnection()
            and set value = ()
```

The error I'm getting is:

This expression was expected to have type IDbConnection but here has type     Devart.Data.Oracle.OracleConnection

Answer (score 8, accepted):

F# does not implement implicit downcasting like C# does, you need to have

```
type public Batch = 
    interface IBatch with
        member f.Connection 
            with get() = new Devart.Data.Oracle.OracleConnection() :> System.Data.IDbConnection
            and set value = ()
```

Comment: Ah. I knew it was a simple syntax detail I was missing. Thanks! Will accept your answer in 10 minutes